# Open MS Access form to new record, but able to edit previous records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a button (edit record) that when clicked it will open a form to edit records, which is what I wanted.  Now I've been requested to make that form open to a new record, but also able to edit previous records.

Can this be done?

The reason for this is that users are quick to start typing and they are actually editing the wrong record.  The new record will allow them to search for the right record first.

Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the new record from *Form Load* of the second form.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acNewRec
End Sub
```

So the user will be at the new record when the form first loads, and can navigate from there to other existing records as needed.

Comment: Works perfect!  Thanks for the help